# Why canActivate and canActivateChild properties are untyped?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) about `Route`, there can be found that `canActivate` and `canActivateChild` are untyped. That seems strange because those properties can be typed using existing interfaces:

```js
  canActivate?: CanActivate[]
  canActivateChild?: CanActivateChild[]
```

Is there a reason why the Angular team prefers to leave those props untyped?

Comment: Your class myCanActivate must implement CanActivate but can be more complex